# Segue from Table View Cell xib with disclosure Indicator to storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I am new in iOS programing and I have an issue. I have a customized table view cell with disclosure indicator in a separate xib file and I want to call a viewcontroller which is in storyboard when the user taps the cell.

Here is the customized table view cell :

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/2qx6w3q.jpg]

Here are the table view (class : TableViewController) that displays the custom table cell and the view (class : ViewController) I want to call when the user taps the customized table view cell :

[image]

Does the view I want to call have to be in a separate xib file or can I let it in my storyboard? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use didSelectRoWAtIndexPath method of table view …DO something like this..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    NSString* viewType = @"YourVCIdentifier";//u can have ContactVC or NavC as other options depending on ur condition
    UIViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewType];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


}
```

that will do it

Answer (score 1):

Use the UITableViewDelegate method

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and push the view controller manually. 
Assign a storyboard ID to the view controller in the storyboard, and then do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your_view_controller_storyboard_ID"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
}
```

This is where you assign a storyboard ID to your view controller:
[image]

And don't forget to set your view controller as your tableView delegate :)